# Extracting the package name of the last installed app on my phone

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, package, android-applicationinfo, package-name

I am writing a code to extract the package name, application name, and icon from the last installed app on my phone. I can get the application common name and icon from the application info, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the package name. All the codes that I have found to get the package name give me the package name of MY app, not the last installed app.

It seems like I need to find a method to get the package name, where I can pass in the application info as the parameter (like I do for the application common name and icon).

```
final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo ai;
try {


ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart(), 0);
Log.d("tag_name","Application Info" + ai);


PACKAGE_NAME = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
Log.d("tag_name","Package Name" + PACKAGE_NAME);



} catch (final PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
ai = null;
}


final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");
Log.d("tag_name", "Application NAME" + applicationName);



// http://www.carbonrider.com/2016/01/01/extract-app-icon-in-android/

try {

Drawable icon = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(ai);
Log.d("tag_name", "ICON" + icon);}
catch (Exception e){}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly receive all apps with this Code :

```
List<PackageInfo> packages = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

Then sort the packages list with this code :

```
 Collections.sort(packages, new Comparator<PackageInfo>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(PackageInfo p1, PackageInfo p2) {
                    return Long.toString(p2.firstInstallTime).compareTo(Long.toString(p1.firstInstallTime));
                }
            });
```

Then you can receive the package Name of the latest installed app this way:

```
packages.get(0).packageName
```